# automating windows phone emulator

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

It's easy to create unit tests for Windows Phone apps (8.0/8.1) that run on the emulator.

Now, it would be great to be able to 'remote control' the emulator from inside such a test (e.g. changing the orientation or the location on the fly).

Does anyone know a way how to do this (or has at least an idea about the way to go)?

EDIT:
I'm using the standard *Phone Unit Test* project template (which uses MSTest) in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poor, you have to provide more information at least about what language, Test framework, tool are you using for your tests?

My article about [Custom Mobile test framework](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/2014/03/custom-mobile-testing-framework.html) maybe useful to you. Feel free to reuse what you find helpful or to ask questions.